How to form a Qualified Expression of an Array Type with a Single Element?
Consider a situation where you need to initialise an (1D) array with a length of one, hence containing a single element, using a qualified expression, like this1:
-- Declaration of type of an integer array:
type t_ints is array (natural range <>) of integer;
-- Assignment of a single-element array:
variable v_ints: t_ints(0 to 0) := t_ints'((1));

Unfortunately, this fails, because (1) is not interpreted as an array with one element, but as an over-parenthesised expression of a scalar integer.
However, the following code snippet, applying two elements, works:
-- Declaration of type of an integer array:
type t_ints is array (natural range <>) of integer;
-- Assignment of a dual-element array:
variable v_ints: t_ints(0 to 1) := t_ints'((1, 2));

This is obviously, because (1, 2) is correctly seen as an array of integers.
So how to correctly provide a qualified expression with an array of just a single element, or how to force (1) to be considered as an array?

The only work-around I found so far is to use an interim constant that holds more than an array element, and then slicing out one element for variable assignment, but this appears quite clumsy:
-- Declaration of type of an integer array:
type t_ints is array (natural range <>) of integer;
-- Declaration of interim auxiliary constant:
constant c_ints: t_ints(0 to 1) := (1, 2);
-- Assignment of a single-element array by slicing:
variable v_ints: t_ints(0 to 0) := c_ints(0 to 0);


1)  This code could appear in the declaration section of a process, for example.

Provide a [mcve] with a specific problem. Have you considered declaring a subtype of t_ints to use as a type mark for the qualified expression? An array aggregate with a single element requires named association.

@user16145658, I don't know how a subtype could help here. What I missed here is the named association for the single-element array…

There are cases when context supplies type and subtype, e.g. here variable v_ints:  t_ints (0 to 0) := (0 => 1);. There can also be cases where the type and subtype are supplied by a qualified expression.

I can see at least three methods for doing this. Using index, using others, or through concatenation o another array:
type t_ints is array (natural range <>) of integer;
constant c_ints_null: t_ints(1 to 0) := (others => 1);
variable v_ints0: t_ints(0 to 0) := (0 => 1);
variable v_ints1: t_ints(0 to 0) := (others => 1);
variable v_ints2: t_ints(0 to 0) := c_ints_null & 1;


Can anyone explain why the line variable v_ints2: t_ints(0 to 0) := c_ints_null & 1; does not give a compile error?

@MatthiasSchweikart, this appends an integer to an empty array of integers (note the null-range 1 to 0 in the declaration of c_ints_null)…

Well, it would have been so easy, just using the named choices notation of the array aggregate (v_ints0) – thanks for that! Moreover, my problem is not linked to Qualified Expressions as I thought. Anyway, what is really interesting is that even (-1 => 1) or t_ints'(-1 => 1) work, even though the index range of t_ints is defined to be of type natural; seems only the base type (integer) is relevant for the indexing…

@MatthiasSchweikart   All single dimensional arrays in VHDL support &.   Concatenating a null array with an scalar value produces an array value.
